# In c# Console crashes whenever I insert a double value

Tags: c#

```
double myDouble = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(myDouble);
//user inputs 3.14 for example
```

When the code runs and the user inserts a double value like 3.14 the console crashes. Why is this? 
Also bear in mind I'm really new to programming and still learning the basics.

Comment: Try with double myDouble = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: @HaDoan I forgot to put console in the example sorry xD

Comment: How are you typing Console.Read.Line(). Even intellisense does not provide that.   double myDouble = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine(myDouble);

Comment: You need to remove the dot between 'read' and 'Line'.

Comment: What is the language of your computer (localization)?

Comment: @abto what like my location?English

Comment: Somebody named "Tomás" should type `3,14`.  Consider using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and double.TryParse().

Comment: Please provide the full error when things are crashing (message, stacktrace)

Comment: If you run a console executable from Visual Studio, it will open a console window when you start debugging. That window will close automatically after the last statement  (in your case `Console.WriteLine()`). Is that what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Your culture probably determine that you should use `','` separator instead of `'.'`. There are 2 decimal separators because in one case you can type like `132,532.34` which means : `132532.34`

2.If you want to check if user wrote it in good format, use `double.TryParse` instead, it will return `0` if parse failed.

3.If you want to parse double with any separator use something like:

```
Double myDouble;
Double defaultValue = 0;
var value = Console.ReadLine();

if (!double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out myDouble ) &&
    // Then try in US english
    !double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out myDouble ) &&
    // Then in neutral language
    !double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myDouble ))
{
    myDouble = defaultValue;
}
Console.WriteLine(myDouble);
```

Comment: [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `bool` (if it returned an integer you wouldn't be able to use it like you do in your code)

Comment: I mean, it will return 0 in out double (double.TryParse( text, out <here>)

Answer (score -3):

```
Console.WriteLine(myDouble.ToString());
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: First of all `ToString()` not `toString()`. Secondly, this is not the problem.

Comment: [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/219hw6yx(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload for `double` parameters, so whatever makes you think using that would cause a crash (or throw an exception)?